# apply regex enhanced match on capturing group

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text :

"This is a first test just before a second"

I want to match test, if preceeded by "first" and followed by "just". I also want to allow for up to one misspelling on test.

I could do something like:

```
import regex

text = "This is a first test just before a second"
text2 = "This is a first ctest just before a second"


pattern = r'(?:first)(test){e<=1}(?:just)'    
match = regex.search(pattern, text, regex.IGNORECASE)
```

However, with the fuzziness allowed, I could potentially return "ctest" with text2.

Using the enhanced match function of regex, something like :

```
pattern = r'(?e)(test){e<=1}'
```

works but I am not able to mix it up with the context words I want to include in the pattern (meaning that 
`r'(?:first)(?e)(test){e<=1}(?:just)'` or `r'(?e)((?:first)(test){e<=1}(?:just))'` do not work and still returns the fuzzy match

Comment: Do you mean you want `pattern = r'(?e)first\s+(?:test){e<=1}\s+just'`? Could you please clarify what you need? Note `{e` is for all errors: substitutions, deletions and insertions. Are you sure you want them all?

Comment: I do not want to capture those context words in the final captured group, I could of course remove them manually from the match, but it's easier if it can be done in the regex itself

Comment: But  you may just access Group 1 value once your regex matches, try `print(match.group(1))`

Comment: See https://rextester.com/EFRL76875 - is it what you need?

Comment: It works! Thanks